# Gate/Policies checks with multiple projects in Laravel

Tags: laravel, policy, projects

I have a question about policies in Laravel. I know I can check userrights with the function `can()`, as example `can('edit-tasks')`; But I have an app with multiple projects. So user John Doe can edit tasks on project X, but not on project Y.
How can I do this in Laravel? I'm searching for a function like: `can('edit_tasks', $user_id, $project_id)`.

How can I do this?

Comment: a better approach would probably be to give each type of a user a role and check for his role in the policy itself. Defining a can() for every user seems a bit overkill and hard to maintain.

Comment: I doubt there is a ready function for this but you can define a middleware for this